# jquery novice cannot load text file

Tags: jquery

Complete newbie to jquery so I have copied a w3schoolsexample and tried to load a text file in the same directory with no joy.

I have a jqueryTest.html  file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");
  });

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

The demo_test.txt file is one word

```
testing
```

When I run the html file I just get a blank page

Obviously a simple error but would appreciate some help

Comment: Never use W3 schools for learning programming. Never.

Comment: Does demo_test.txt reside on the root of your website? Also are you running this from a web server or just a browser pointed at a file?

Comment: Try to add `http://`` in front of the JQuery URL

Comment: `"I just get a blank page"` - Are you sure you don't also get a console error?  Is the jQuery code even executing?  Is the network request being made for the text file?  What is the response of that request?  Monitor this with a browser debugging tool (FireBug, Chrome developer tools, etc.) and see what's actually going on.

Comment: @sdespont In this case, he is probably running a local file, so your solution does work, my bad.

Comment: w3schools is a nice place to start, but sometimes you need more depth. Is this file in the same directory as your .html file? http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Actually `//` will only work if running on a server

Comment: @agrothe That was the problem. I had been running other html out of a file that was not in a web server. Now that I have switched the jquery works

Comment: @Brad M Thanks for tip - from the upticks this is clearly a good warning

Comment: @pssguy, I posted the info as an answer

Comment: Tx Accepted. hope helps others avoid same fate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a web page from a file location, ie. `file:///C:/` there are stricter permissions on what scripts can run.

Make sure when testing javascript that you run from a web server, if it is a local server.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to specify the `text/javascript` as the `type` of script in the script tags. I know that in certain occasions, this can actually be a source of problems. This would mean that the following would be used instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");
    });

</script>
```

Another point, w3schools is perhaps not the best tool for learning jQuery. It is useful as a reference for use, but as for the learning of jQuery, it is not very descriptive and this can hinder any learning whatever that may be.